# Editing two separate sections in two separate sessions merges changes

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I performed [two separate edits](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/72270) to this topic in two separate editing sessions, but they got merged into one. Did I do something wrong, or if not, I would like to suggest that we add a feature to keep edits to separate sections separate.

Comment: That is how it works - and I would be happy too if single edit sessions were handled as single "transactions" to get approved or rejected...